# Venturi Injector

Tags: pumps

I have a venturi injector attached to a pump. I am using this injector to draw air naturally into the system when water is the prime fluid. However, I am seeing the discharge pressure of the pump is fluctuating from 13 psig to 16 psig. The pump is a centrifugal pump and it is situated on the bottom of the tank. The static head is 5ft from pump centerline. To my understanding, it feels like the water is getting boiled in the venturi and creating cavitation.

How can I prevent cavitation in venturi? If the outlet pressure remains fixed, does increasing inlet pressure stop the water from being boiled in the venturi?

Comment: if you are injecting air prior to the inlet, much more likely is you are trying to pump air, not water vapor.

Comment: the air is injected naturally through the venturi throat. there is no air being pumped as the pump and system are  always primed before running.

Comment: what is the temeprature of the water? Can you measure absolute air pressure on the air inlet of the injector, or water pressure near the injector? I assume you checked other possible sources of the vibration.

Answer (score 1):

Water is very easy to vaporize with a pump.  One can vaporize water near earth atmosphere conditions with just the pump alone- just fill pump with water and restrict the intake.  Not only will the suction drop pressure, but the pump may start to overheat too helping boil that water!  This is one of the reasons why one generally submerges a pump into a well rather than attempting to suck it up.

You likely need a setup that does not allow such a large drop in pressure at that intake.  A less restrictive (and less effective) venturi might make it feasible or you might be able to place pumps upstream rather than downstream of the venturi (exposure to air source pressure at the venturi will limit how much you can pressurize though!).

You could also go the conventional route of just compressing air into the water.

Comment: What do you mean by "vaporize air"?

Comment: @ElliotAldersonE was mistype.  tried fixing, mean to indicate that pressure near atmospheric matters.  i'd appreciate any help rewording.